# Trouble installing Ubuntu Studio on separate internal hard drive

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, ubuntu-studio

I am wanting to install Ubuntu Studio onto a separate internal hard drive than what my windows 7 is installed on, the part I'm having trouble with is the fact that this drive is not empty, so I'd only be able to use a certain percentage of the drive for ubuntu. The drive has about 30gbs of free space, how can I install ubuntu onto this drive without loosing all the data on the rest of the drive? Am having trouble understanding the partitioning system for this situation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your drive is not completely full you can  resize your existing partition and create a new partition with  Ubuntu Lice CD.

- Boot from media ie USB or CD and choose Try Ubuntu.
- Now  open GParted partition editor.

[image]

- In GParted window select your hard disk from the dropdown list present in  top right cornrer.(You partition arrangement will be different.)

[image]

- You should create 2 partitions, one for mount `/` and the other for swap.
  1 Gib swap partition is sufficient.
- Click on the partition and select **Resize/Move**.

[image]

- It will open a popup window. The easiest way to resize a partition is by clicking and dragging the handles at either side of the bar, although you can also enter exact numbers.

[image]

- Once you are satisfied with your partition arrangement, Apply it. it will create some unallocated space.
- Create 2 partitions in unallocated space .
- Now you can install Ubuntu on this partition.
- After starting the installation, select **Something else** when **Installation Type** window appears.
- Select partition on which you wan to install Ubuntu, with  type as `EXT4` and mount point as `/`.
- Select swap partition and select type as  linux-swap.
- As it is your internal hard drive, changing the place of grub installation is not necessary.
- Now click Next to proceed the installation process.